# Edge tabs vs Vertice tabs?

Tags: direct-manipulation

I'm trying to figure out when edge tabs would be more fitting vs vertice tabs and vice versa.

the main purpose here is to design an editing system that allows for easy manipulation of elements.

I've included drawings to help illustrate my question.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Why not both? Adobe XD and Illustrator do this. I tend to err on the side of applications that are used by millions of people. If they are already familiar with those type of controls then they shouldn't have a problem if you used the same pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Both types are suitable for this "job" and even a combination of them, but you shouldn't break [Jakob's law](https://lawsofux.com/jakobs-law/), which means the tabs and interaction with them must be familiar to the main target audience.

If your TA typically spends a day e.g. in Figma, Miro, Jira the tabs need to keep similar with them.

[image: Figma and Miro tabs]

Please, conduct your own user behavioral observation.

Answer (score 0):

I would have different interpretations of those options.

With vertice tabs I expect to be able to scale the box by dragging one corner further out or in. Possibly this would distort the aspect ratio of the element, which might be able to be maintained by holding a key on the keyboard.

With edge tabs I would expect the shape would not scale when dragging but rather increase the width or height of the element depending on which I drag.

As per another answer, I am a designer more familiar with design tools so this is just my interpretation. Your users might have different interpretations so best to research.